# BMC Helix Remedyforce Single Sign on from oneLogin

Tags: salesforce, onelogin, remedy

I'm trying to configure Single sign-on in BMC RemedyForce by using onelogin. But failed to connect it. Getting below mentioned error when doing SAML Validator:

Results

Last recorded SAML login failure:  2019-11-07T07:44:20.952Z
Unexpected Exceptions
  Ok
1. Validating the Status
  Ok
2. Looking for an Authentication Statement
  Ok
3. Looking for a Conditions statement
  Ok
4. Checking that the timestamps in the assertion are valid
  Ok
5. Checking that the Attribute namespace matches, if provided
  Not Provided
6. Miscellaneous format confirmations
  Ok
7. Confirming Issuer matches
  Ok
8. Confirming a Subject Confirmation was provided and contains valid timestamps
  Ok
9. Checking that the Audience matches
  Audience problems
  The audience in the assertion did not match the allowed audiences
  Allowed audiences: [https://iblrf.my.salesforce.com]
10. Checking the Recipient
  Ok
11. Validating the Signature
  Is the response signed? false
  Is the assertion signed? true
  Is the correct certificate supplied in the keyinfo? true
  Ok
12. Checking that the Site URL Attribute contains a valid site url, if provided
  Not Provided
13. Looking for portal and organization id, if provided
  Ok
14. Checking if session security level is valid, if provided
  Ok

Subject: owais.nasar@ibl-unisys.com
Unable to map the subject to a Salesforce.com user

AssertionId: pfx201ceae2-5532-2c9f-60b9-b8ebb53a166b

and when login through onelogin
Single Sign-On Error

We can't log you in. Check for an invalid assertion in the SAML Assertion Validator (available in Single Sign-On Settings) or check the login history for failed logins.

Similarly, onelogin Mircosoft Active directory fetch only two users whereas in MS Server AD contains 9 users.

Answer (score 0):

Two issues there.
**The audience in the assertion did not match the allowed audiences Allowed audiences: [https://iblrf.my.salesforce.com]**

That's pretty clear. You can usually bypass this kind of error by uploading the Onelogin metadata to Salesforce and then those values get populated automatically.

The main issue is also pretty simple.
**Subject: owais.nasar@ibl-unisys.com Unable to map the subject to a Salesforce.com user**

Your salesforce tenant does not have an account for the user you have logged into Onelogin with. Depending on your SSO settings, you'll need to create an account with a user name and potentially email address of : owais.nasar@ibl-unisys.com

All done.